# Format time data pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have dates in this format: `2015-02-02 14:19:00`.

I use this code:

```py
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
df = pd.read_csv('3df_uniti.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col='date', date_parser=dateparse)
df.head()
```

but it doesn't work because it gives me the follow error:

> time data does not match format

Can you help me to set the right format?

Comment: your format uses `/` instead of `-`. Try changing it to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`

Comment: It works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format uses `/` instead of `-`. Try changing it to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.